# Lambda least occurring element

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class TaughtSubject
{
    public int TaughtSubjectId { get; set; }

    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public Form FormId { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I received a list of these objects and I want to get the least occurring one by the `SubjectId` then by `FormId`. I also want to get back the first **whole** element. Not just the property.

Here is my attempt:

```
var teacher = taughtSubjects.GroupBy(t => t.SubjectId).OrderBy(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key).First();
```

But this only returns the SubjectId. I want the whole teacher object and to also add the second sort condition `FormId`.

Comment: So the first item of the least occurring FormId of the least occurring SubjectId? Is that correct? So identifying the minimum count of SubjectId, and within that group, identifying the minimum count of FormId, and then within that group take the first item?

Comment: Instead of `Select(g => g.Key)` try `SelectMany(g => g)`. (I'm too tired to think now if this is correct ;p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. You need the first item of the Lookup (the result of the GroupBy you have), and then in the values for that element of the lookup you want to group by FormId and return the teacher(s) with the least-occurring one of those.

```
var teachers = taughtSubjects
   .GroupBy(ts => ts.SubjectId)
   .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
   .ThenBy(g=>g.Key) //tiebreaker
   .First() //gets the IEnumerable of Teachers that teach this least-taught subject
   .GroupBy(t=>t.FormId)
   .OrderBy(g=>g.Count())
   .ThenBy(g=>g.Key) //as a tiebreaker
   .First() //gets the teacher(s) with the lowest specified FormId.
```

This will return an IEnumerable of Teachers with at least one element, representing the teacher(s) who teach the least-taught subject with the least-used form.

Understand that there may be Subjects in your system that aren't taught at all. They will not be represented here, because no teacher exists that teaches the class. The query will only consider subjects with at least one teacher.

**EDIT:** After rereading your question, I think I understand what's going on. These "taught subjects" relate to a particular subject (math, reading, science, art, music) taught to a particular "form" or "grade level" (1st grade-12th grade in the US system).

As you currently have your object set up, duplicate entries for the same subject and grade are possible, but they would be indistinguishable other than by the TaughtSubjectID field (which may just be assigned from a counter or identity).

It would make more sense, no matter how you'd want this done, to also include the Teacher in the TaughtSubject. That would, for instance, allow you to list the teachers who teach the least-taught subject in the least-taught grade for that subject, or alternately as David B suggests, the least-taught overall combination of subject and grade.

Which one you want is subjective, and there is a semantic difference. It is possible for Music to be the least-taught subject (only offered to 9th-12th graders), but for there to be two or three teachers teaching it at every grade level. Math on the other hand may be taught at every grade level with a high number of teachers overall and thus have a higher number of TaughtSubject records than Music, but there may only be one 6th-grade Math teacher out of the whole group. Finding the least-taught grade of the least-taught subject would give you 9th-grade Music. Finding the least-taught overall subject-grade combination would give you 6th grade Math.

Comment: The teacher is already included in the model, I just exclude it for SO purpose. I'll add it

Comment: And yea, your edit is exactly why I want to find the least taught subject so I can assign these teachers to actual classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a second grouping, not a second sort condition:

```
IEnumerable<TaughtSubject> firstGroup = taughtSubjects
  .GroupBy(t => t.SubjectId)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
  .First()  //the taughtsubjects that are members of the smallest subject group.
  .GroupBy(t => t.FormId)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
  .First(); // and of these taughtsubjects, the members of the smallest form group.

  // and the first member of those.
TaughtSubject firstElement = firstGroup.First();
```

---

Above is what you asked for, but most people would want the smallest group for a given form and subject pairing.  That's done this way.

```
IEnumerable<TaughtSubject> firstGroup = taughtSubjects
  .GroupBy(t => new {t.FormId, t.SubjectId})
  .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
  .First();

  // and the first member of those.
TaughtSubject firstElement = firstGroup.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use OrderBy and ThenBy:

```
public class foo
{
    public int e1 { get; set; }
    public int e2 { get; set; }
    public int e3 { get; set; }
    public int e4 { get; set; }

    public foo(int e1, int e2, int e3, int e4)
    {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
        this.e3 = e3;
        this.e4 = e4;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("e1 = {0}\te2 = {1}\te3 = {2}\te4 = {3}",
            e1, e2, e3, e4);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<foo> foosList = new List<foo>();
    Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        foosList.Add(new foo(r.Next(20), r.Next(20), r.Next(10), r.Next(5)));

    List<foo> result = foosList.OrderBy(e => e.e4).ThenBy(e => e.e3).ToList();
    result.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
e1 = 7  e2 = 4  e3 = 2  e4 = 0
e1 = 18 e2 = 12 e3 = 4  e4 = 0
e1 = 9  e2 = 8  e3 = 6  e4 = 0
e1 = 6  e2 = 8  e3 = 6  e4 = 0
e1 = 13 e2 = 14 e3 = 8  e4 = 0
e1 = 6  e2 = 15 e3 = 1  e4 = 2
e1 = 18 e2 = 10 e3 = 1  e4 = 2
e1 = 14 e2 = 3  e3 = 8  e4 = 2
e1 = 7  e2 = 3  e3 = 3  e4 = 3
e1 = 11 e2 = 6  e3 = 4  e4 = 3
e1 = 11 e2 = 17 e3 = 1  e4 = 4
e1 = 16 e2 = 1  e3 = 2  e4 = 4
e1 = 16 e2 = 11 e3 = 7  e4 = 4
e1 = 12 e2 = 5  e3 = 8  e4 = 4
e1 = 7  e2 = 7  e3 = 9  e4 = 4
```

Comment: @leppie: why grouping? He needs "least occurring element" which is result[0]

Comment: But there can be more than 1 element matching the criteria.

Comment: "least occurring element" is the element having a property that is the rarest among the sample space. In your example, the value of e4 == 3 only occurs twice, so those two records contain the "least-occurring element" of interest, and then between those two each distinct e3 only occurs once so either of them (probably the lower value) is the one the OP wants. Your method and thus your answer are wrong.

Comment: @KeithS: thanks for the explaination, I've slightly misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from ts in TaughtSubjects
let leastSubjId = taughtSubjects.GroupBy(t => t.SubjectId).OrderBy(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key).First()
where ts.SubjectId == leastSubjId
select ts
```

You can add another condition like that if you want to.

Comment: Or you can always take it outside if you want.

Comment: That would work, but I think the OP wants the 'special' single expression :)

Comment: That's why it's inside the single statement :P

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you don't try to do that in a single expression. It's going to be very hard for a reader to understand what's going on. Break it into two expressions, one for subjectid one for formid.

Comment: That is not an answer to his question... put it as a comment or suggest the answer.